# Copy/paste code vs. using as a plugin or gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, gemfile

**Problem**: Both the gem and plugin for "table_builder" do not deploy to heroku using rails 3.1. They end up with bugs.

**Current Solution**: Copying the table_builder.rb and calendar_helper.rb from https://github.com/p8/table_builder and putting directly in the "app/helpers" folder

I feel this is the wrong way to go; however, is there any problem with it if it works?